# jQuery Masonry with separators?

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, jquery-masonry

I am implementing jQuery Masonry and I got it just fine.

Then I wanted to add `headings/separators` throughout (date dividers)... To make this work I had to put each `"group"` into it's own container and masonry each of those. If I just masonry the main container, it absolutely positions them all at the very top `covering/ignoring` the heading dividers.

Is there any way I can `"switch"` between the two? If I `hide()` the separators and reload each of the masonry they still form their own groups. If i `float` each of the containers, it just becomes a complete mess.

How could I accomplish this without a reload and formatting the `HTML/JS` calls?

Comment: You dont have a live example? http://jsbin.com/ ? :)

Comment: is [this](http://films.imhonet.ru/) similar you are going to reach?